# Depiction Error with amsmath and book class template

Tags: equations, amsmath, books

I have a Problem with the depiction of equations, especially the `\sum` sign is not correctly displayed, it looks like a big parenthesis, als the `\in` operator is displayed as a French special character ("mute E"):

[image]
or as code:

```
   $u \in [0,1]$ so that the function has the form  \cite[p. 117 ff]{piegl1996nurbs}
     \begin{equation}
            \displaystyle C(u) =  \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} R_{i,p}(u)P_{i}  
     \end{equation}
```

, the template that I am using is the 'wissdoc' based on the book class, while using overleaf and the pdfLaTex compiler, here are some of the dependencies listed :

[image]

code form wissdoc.cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01] % Sorry, wir brauchen LaTeX2e!
\ProvidesClass{wissdoc}[2023 Wissenschaftliches Dokument]
\LoadClass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage, scrartcl, singlespaced]{book} % diese Klasse basiert auf ``book''
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      % T1-encoded fonts: auch Wörter mit Umlauten trennen
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
%\usepackage{ae}               % almost european, virtueller T1-Font
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}  % um Graphiken einzubinden
\usepackage{makeidx}          % wir wollen auch einen Index
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry} % Seitenränder einstellen leichtgemacht
\usepackage{fancyhdr}         % definiere einfache Headings (mindestens V 1.99c
                              % notwendig)
\usepackage[xindy, acronym, toc, style=long, nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage[nottoc, notlot, notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{array}          % fuer aufwändigere Tabellen
\usepackage{xcolor}     % Farbunterstützung
\usepackage{colortbl}       % farbige Tabellen
\usepackage{longtable}      % seitenübergreifende Tabellen
%\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[T1]{url} % much like \verb allow line breaks for paths and URLs
\usepackage{textcomp} %für textdegree stuff 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{datetime2}

\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.gif}{png}{.png}{convert gif:#1 png:\OutputFile}
\AppendGraphicsExtensions{.gif}
% Autorenangaben
%\usepackage[german]{authblk}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, backend=biber, style=iso-numeric, citestyle=numeric-comp, maxbibnames=2, firstinits=true]{biblatex}
```

code from thesis.tex:

```
\documentclass{wissdoc}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% Abschlussarbeit - Hauptdokument
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
%%
%%
% wissdoc Optionen: draft, relaxed, pdf --> siehe wissdoc.cls
% ------------------------------------------------------------------
% Weitere packages: (Dokumentation dazu durch "latex <package>.dtx")
%\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

% \usepackage{ngerman} % 
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} % deutsche und englische Spracheinstellungen  bsp. für Umlaute etc., keine Rechtschreibprüfung
\usepackage{acronym} % Abkürzungsverzeichnis mit Abkürzungen

% Schriftart
% needs to be loaded before glossaries
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[nottoc, notlot, notlof]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
% Set page size and margins
% Replace `letterpaper' with`a4paper' for UK/EU standard size
\usepackage{float}
% Useful packages
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{wasysym, manfnt, fontawesome}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{incgraph}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\usepackage{movie15}
%Schriftart
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;} 

\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%

\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}

% Mathe, Symbole, Einheitendarstellung, Chemie
% \usepackage{siunitx}  

% Typographie
\usepackage[auto]{microtype}

% Autorenangaben
\usepackage[german]{authblk}

%\renewcommand\Authand{, }
%\renewcommand\Authands{, }

%Paket zur Erstellung von Gantt-Charts
% \usepackage{pgfgantt}

% Darstellung der Literaturangaben
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=iso-numeric, citestyle=numeric-comp, maxbibnames=2, firstinits=true]{biblatex}


% pdf-Einstellungen
% Angaben ggf. aktualisieren!
% Links nicht einrahmen
%\usepackage[pdftitle={}, pdfsubject={}, pdfauthor={}, pdfkeywords={}, hidelinks]{hyperref}

% useful packages:
\usepackage{amsmath} % Standardpaket für Bereich Mathematik
\usepackage{rotating} % Rotation von z.B. Bildern, Tabellen etc.
\usepackage{enumitem} % Kontrolle über Layout von itemize, enumerate, description
\usepackage{pdfpages} % Seiten aus PDF/ ganzes PDF einbinden
\usepackage{newunicodechar} % Bedeutung von Unicode Characters definieren, Nutzung über \newunicodechar{}{}
\usepackage{longtable} % for 'longtable' environment
\usepackage{pdflscape} % for 'landscape' environment
\usepackage{changepage}

% \usepackage{varioref}
% \usepackage{verbatim}
% \usepackage{float}    %z.B. \floatstyle{ruled}\restylefloat{figure}
% \usepackage{subfigure}
% \usepackage{fancybox} % für schattierte,ovale Boxen etc.
% \usepackage{tabularx} % automatische Spaltenbreite
% \usepackage{supertab} % mehrseitige Tabellen
%% ---------------- end of usepackages -------------

%% Informationen für die PDF-Datei
\hypersetup{
 pdfauthor={},
 pdftitle={tbd}
 pdfsubject={Not set},
 pdfkeywords={Not set}
}

% Print URLs not in Typewriter Font
\def\UrlFont{\rm}

\newcommand{\blankpage}{% Leerseite ohne Seitennummer, nächste Seite rechts
 \clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
}

%% Einstellungen für das gesamte Dokument

% Trennhilfen
% Wichtig! 
% Im ngerman-paket sind zusätzlich folgende Trennhinweise enthalten:
% "- = zusätzliche Trennstelle
% "| = Vermeidung von Ligaturen und mögliche Trennung (bsp: Schaf"|fell)
% "~ = Bindestrich an dem keine Trennung erlaubt ist (bsp: bergauf und "~ab)
% "= = Bindestrich bei dem Worte vor und dahinter getrennt werden dürfen
% "" = Trennstelle ohne Erzeugung eines Trennstrichs (bsp: und/""oder)

% Trennhinweise fuer Woerter hier beschreiben
\hyphenation{
% Pro-to-koll-in-stan-zen
% Ma-na-ge-ment  Netz-werk-ele-men-ten
% Netz-werk Netz-werk-re-ser-vie-rung
% Netz-werk-adap-ter Fein-ju-stier-ung
% Da-ten-strom-spe-zi-fi-ka-tion Pa-ket-rumpf
% Kon-troll-in-stanz
}

% Index-Datei öffnen
\ifnotdraft{\makeindex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% includeonly %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Es werden nur die Teile eingebunden, die hier 
% aufgefuehrt sind!
\includeonly{
chapters/abstract, % Abstract 
abbreviations, %  
title_page,%
explanation,% Pflicht für Abschlussarbeiten
chapters/introduction,% Motivation, Zielsetzung, Gliederung
chapters/theory,% Grundlagen 
chapters/relatedwork,   % Related Work
chapters/implementation,  % Beschreibung der Umsetzung/Implementierung, Problemlösung (Konzepte, allg. Architektur, ...)
chapters/evaluation,      % Nachweis und Auswertung
chapters/discussion,    % Diskussion
chapters/conclusion,  % Zusammenfassung der Ergebnisse und Ausblick
attachment
}

% Speicherort der Literaturangaben (*.bib Datei)
{\footnotesize
\bibliography{literature/refs}
}



\makeglossaries

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\include{commands.tex}
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}
\ifnotdraft{
\include{title_page}
\blankpage % Leerseite auf Titelrückseite
 %
 % Die folgende Erklärung ist für Diplomarbeiten Pflicht
 % (siehe Prüfungsordnung), für Studienarbeiten nicht notwendig
 \include{explanation}
 \blankpage % Leerseite auf Erklärungsrückseite
}
%
%% *************** Ab hier geht's los****************
\include{chapters/abstract}
%% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
%% Verzeichnisse
%% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

\ifnotdraft{
    {\parskip 0pt\tableofcontents} % toc bitte einzeilig
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \include{abbreviations.tex}
}

%% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
%% Hauptteil
%% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\graphicspath{{images/}}

\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{chapters/introduction}  % Einleitung
\include{chapters/theory}  % Grundlagen
\include{chapters/relatedwork}     % Related Work
\include{chapters/implementation}    % Implementierung
\include{chapters/evaluation}        % Evaluierung
\include{chapters/discussion}   % Discussion
\include{chapters/conclusion}   % Zusammenfassung und Ausblick
%% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
%% Literatur
%% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
%  mit dem Befehl \nocite werden auch nicht 
%  zitierte Referenzen abgedruckt
\cleardoublepage
%\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
%%
\nocite{*} % nur angeben, wenn auch nicht im Text zitierte Quellen 
           % erscheinen sollen
 % abbrvnat unsrtnat alpha unsrt accessabbrv
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\printbibliography[title={References}]
%% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
%% Anhang
%% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

\appendix
\include{attachment}
%\include{anhang_b}
```

Comment: don't show code as an image, we can not debug that. make a small complete document that shows the problem, but I would guess you are mixing a package with nonstandard font encodings (mdsymbol or fdsymbol or stix, perhaps) with a package using the standard encodings such as amssymb

Comment: Thanks, im quite new to latex, where are those non standart from encodings normaly placed in the .cls or .bst file?

Comment: `\usepackage{mnsymbol}` or `\RequirePackage{mnsymbol}` anywhere in a class or package or your document preamble. But loading such a package is not wrong, it is loading two packages with different encodings that is wrong, but you have shown no code to produce the error so impossible to suggest a fix

Comment: unrelated but don't use `\displaystyle` or `\limits` (neither do anything at all in the fragment you show). But you still have not shown any usable code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i searched for mdsymbol , fdsymbol or stix in both in the main.tex file and the wissdoc.cls file no trace of those dependencys. I dont understand which code you are talking about?  Also removing `\limits` and `\displaystyle` makes no diffrence.

Comment: Create a minimal file that shows the problem. Update your question with that code (not as image).

Comment: your code fragment should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` so people can see the problem and debug it. It is easy for you to make a small example, start with a copy of your document and delete every package you can delete while the problem shows. (if you delete a package and the problem goes, you have solved the problem yourself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
```

and

```
\usepackage{fourier}
```

Either use the former pair of packages or the latter packages. Loading both `libertinust1math` and `fourier` is the cause of your problem.

Comment: i didnt see your answer before, but i found the issue myself but you did 1 hour before me. Thank you